# Is auto an optional keyword in ranged based for loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, auto, c++17

I recall someone once telling me,

> "there is no need for `auto` inside range-based for loops.   It would
>   **not** be ambiguous in the language if we were to remove it."

Is that a true statement?
Is the folowing code valid C++ syntax?

```
for (elem : range){...}
```

I had assumed this was already valid syntax, but when I went to compile with
`clang++ --std=c++1z`, I was shown the following error:

```
range-based for loop requires type for loop variable
 for (elem: range){
```

The compiler still recognizes this as a range-based for loop, so why can't it also derive the type?

Comment: This was discussed for introduction in C++17.  For this proposal to make even sense, it had to be argued that the syntax remains unambiguous, which is what the quote does. I'm not sure how the current state of affairs is, though.

Comment: @5gon12eder: I think it was received with much concern, especially regarding the question of name shadowing (e.g. whether `elem` is already a name in scope, what if someone adds it later, etc.

Comment: This syntax was proposed by Stephan T Lavavej for C++17, and it would be syntactic sugar for `for(auto&& elem : range)`. IIRC clang implemented this as part of `-std=c++1z`, but when the proposal got rejected, they probably changed that into an error.

Comment: As far as I can remember, the committee hated the idea of a variable being declared without a type or `auto`, as in it's not explicit enough, just like they rejected `[](x, y) {...}` (although `[x=2](){}` was accepted).

Comment: As @Praetorian mentioned, this didn't pass through. Watch Bjarne's talk on this: https://youtu.be/2egL4y_VpYg?t=1h7m45s

Answer (score 10):

The:

```
for (elem : range){...}
```

syntax is not currently valid but there was a proposal to make this valid syntax and the syntax is supported in gcc 5.2 (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/e063FFw2u6yFQ9cH)*):

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v ;

    for( elem : v )
    {
    }
}
```

and if we try this in C++14 mode it says:

> warning: range-based for loop without a type-specifier only available
>   with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z

So this would clearly work and has been implemented in gcc. It looks like this feature was removed in gcc 6.0.

As far as I can tell this was implemented in gcc with the expectation that [proposal N3853: Range-Based For-Loops: The Next Generation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm) would be accepted but it was rejected and the updated version [N3994](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm) says:

> This updates N3853 (see [1]) which proposed the syntax "for (elem :
>   range)", by adding support for attributes and answering additional
>   questions. Please see the original proposal for the rationale behind
>   this feature, which is not repeated here.

We can see it was rejected from the [EWG issue 81](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4421.html#81) and we can also see this from the [Urbana meeting minutes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html). Although there are many issues with the proposal I believe STL made a convincing set of arguments in the Question and Answers section of the proposal and I was disappointed that the proposal was rejected.

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you disappointed in typeless lambda parameters being rejected? `[](x, y) {}` for example.

Comment: @chris well the issues raised in [Appendix B of N3559](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3559.pdf) seem easier to accept as real problems to me but perhaps I am missing some details of the objections to N3994.

Comment: True, and I forgot about concepts in lambdas vs. them being less useful in range-based for loops. I was particularly fond of the loop type omission as well.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax requires a type for a range-for statement, even if it's `auto`. `for (elem : range) {...}` is a syntax error, so technically, yes, it's true, the language could state that this is equivalent to `for (auto elem : range) {...}`.

There are at least two major problems with that, though:

The first is that `for (T elem : range)` doesn't require `T` to use `auto`. If the compiler sees `for (elem`, it wouldn't yet have any way of knowing whether `elem` is some `typedef` from an outer scope, or a newly declared variable. It's not ambiguous, but it's a bit complicated for compilers to handle correctly.

The second is that you then get the question of what the default should be. Legitimate arguments could be made for `auto`. Legitimate arguments could be made for `auto &`. Legitimate arguments could be made for `const auto &`. The current approach just lets the programmer choose. Legitimate arguments could probably (I'm not entirely sure) also be made for some of those with `auto` replaced by `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: It's a good point that `auto` is not the best option in many (perhaps even most) cases, and therefore shouldn't be an implicit default.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a question for ELL...

The sentence is written in the subjunctive case, meaning that it is talking about a purely hypothetical situation, not the actual language rules.  Subjunctive is used for counterfactual situations.

Comment: I'm asking about the language rules.  If it's not a part of the language, then I suppose the answer is just "no".  But with the in-flush of proposals, and the spiked growth of C++, I'm not sure where I can verify if this is already defined in the language, and if my compiler just needs to catch up.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: C++1z is still being edited.  Are you asking about the latest draft (at https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard, upper left corner)?

Comment: Yeah, the latest draft.  A confirmation that this will indeed be supported in the future.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: If the change happens, you'll find it in the grammar construct *for-range-declaration*.  Right now it still requires the type.

Comment: Ok, I assume it has only been proposed then.