# Range-for-loops and std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, range, auto

Why does this code work

```
std::vector<int> intVector(10);
for(auto& i : intVector)
    std::cout << i;
```

And this doesn't?

```
std::vector<bool> boolVector(10);
for(auto& i : boolVector)
    std::cout << i;
```

In the latter case, I get an error

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::_Bit_reference&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::_Bit_iterator::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}’
>
> ```
> for(auto& i : boolVector)
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way of using C++11's range-based for?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15927033/3425536) (search for "vector<bool>")

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Because [`std::vector<bool>` is not a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794569/why-is-vectorbool-not-a-stl-container) !

`std::vector<T>`'s iterators usually dereference to a `T&`, which you can bind to your own `auto&`.

`std::vector<bool>`, however, packs its `bool`s together inside integers, so you need a proxy to do the bit-masking when accessing them. Thus, its iterators return a `Proxy`.
And since the returned `Proxy` is an prvalue (a temporary), it cannot bind to an lvalue reference such as `auto&`.

The solution : use `auto&&`, which will correctly collapse into an lvalue reference if given one, or bind and maintain the temporary alive if it's given a proxy.

Comment: The proxy is actually a prvalue.

Comment: C++17 solution (hopefully): just use [`for(i : boolVector)`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3853.htm)

Comment: @jingyu9575 [that proposal was rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32706369/1708801) although gcc did support that feature for a while.

Comment: The solution in this case is to use `auto const`, as the code doesn't need to write through the proxy.

Comment: @T.C. thank you ! I'm off reviewing my value categories :p

Comment: @Quentin & T.C What does the term "Proxy" mean?

Comment: @John a thing sitting between what you're accessing and you. Here it's there to convert between booleans on your side and packed bits on the storage's side.

Answer (score 11):

`std::vector<bool>` does not obey the standard container rules.

In particular, its iterators' `operator*` do not return `bool&`.

The loop in the invalid code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::vector<bool> boolVector(10);
  for (auto& i: boolVector)
      std::cout << i;
}
```

can be rewritten in any of three ways to iterate through the values:

1. (read-only)

   ```
    for (auto const i: boolVector)
        std::cout << i;
   ```
2. (read-only, possibly inefficient¹)

   ```
    for (auto const& i: boolVector)  
        std::cout << i;
   ```
3. (read/write²)

   ```
    for (auto&& i: boolVector)
        std::cout << i;
   ```

The choice between the first and last is down to whether you need to modify the values in the vector, or just to read them.

---

Notes:

1. I say "*possibly* inefficient" because it has an unnecessary level of indirection. Any decent optimizer ought to create the same code as for the first sample.
2. `for (auto i: boolVector)` also gives a *read/write* view on the vector (because we have made a copy of the *proxy object*).  But I don't recommend that, because readers will likely expect such writes to have only local effect, as would happen with standard containers.

   And that's why I use `auto const i` for the read-only case; alternatively we could obtain a proxy-of-const using `boolVector | std::views::as_const` (since C++23) or by using a const reference to the vector (`for (auto const& v = boolVector; auto i: v)`).

Answer (score 6):

[`vector<bool>` is (usually) specialized explicitly to store each `bool` in a single bit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), reducing the storage costs from one byte per value to one byte per eight values. No processor I know of offhand is bit addressable, so it's impossible to store a reference to the values in the `vector<bool>`. You need to use plain `auto`, not `auto&` for the iteration value `i`.