# How to use C++11 range-based for with QJsonArray

Tags: qt, c++11, for-loop

With old-style loops, I can delve into a `QJsonArray` and, in the example below, add element "foo" with contents of existing element "bar" for each array item. How can I do this using C++11 range-based for?

```
// QJsonArray oldArray contains an array of which one element is "bar"
QJsonArray newArray;
int i, b = oldArray.count();
for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    QJsonObject element = oldArray.at(i).toObject();
    element["foo"] = element["bar"];
    newArray.append(element);
}
```

I have tried the following (admittedly as trial and error):

### auto&

```
for (auto& element : oldArray) {
    element["foo"] = element["bar];
    newArray.append(element);
}
```

I get the error

> non-const lvalue reference to type 'QJsonValueRef' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'QJsonValueRef'

### const auto&

```
for (const auto& element : oldArray) {
...
```

I get a warning

> loop variable 'element' is always a copy because the range of type 'QJsonArray' does not return a reference

### const auto

```
for (const auto element : oldArray) {
    element["foo"] = element["bar];
    ...
```

I get the error

> no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const QJsonValueRef'

relating to `element["bar"]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the iterator for `QJsonArray` returns a temporary `QJsonValueRef` object, and lvalue references can not bind to temporaries. We can either hold that temporary by value:

```
// QJsonArray oldArray contains an array of which one element is "bar"
QJsonArray newArray;
for (auto v : oldArray) {
    QJsonObject element = v.toObject();
    element["foo"] = element["bar"];
    newArray.append(element);
}
```

In this case `v` is a `QJsonValueRef` object (similar to what `oldArray.at(i)` gives in the old-style loop). After that, we convert that `QJsonValueRef` to a `QJsonObject` using [`.toObject()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toObject-1).

Or we can use forwarding references since they can bind to rvalues:

```
for (auto&& v : oldArray) {
    ...
}
```

In this case `v` is deduced to be an rvalue reference to a `QJsonValueRef`.

Both solutions are identical in terms of the number of objects being created/destructed (since in the former, the copy is elided under [C++17 guaranteed copy elision rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/2666212) or even in pre-C++17 when using any decent compiler. In the latter, the reference is bound to the temporary and this [prolongs its lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) to match the whole iteration).

---

#### Notes

1. This problem is similar to what happens when [using range-based-for with a `std::vector<bool>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34079390/2666212); since both `std::vector<bool>` and `QJsonArray`have iterators that return proxy objects.
2. If using the Clang code model, the second solution generates the warning "loop variable 'v' is always a copy because the range of type 'QJsonArray' does not return a reference". [See this question for an explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066139/what-is-clangs-range-loop-analysis-diagnostic-about)

Comment: @user3606329 My starting point was “I want to use range-based for to iterate QJsonArray but was stuck with a load of errors.” I started asking the question - surely totally valid for StackOverflow - then worked out the answer and why, so thought I’d share it.

Comment: @Mike I have edited the answer to use `auto&&`. If for no other reason, it avoids an unnecessary copy, making it a better solution.

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone, first of all it is not a copy, it is a move. Second, Your explanation is still a bit off. The iterator for `QJsonArray` returns an [rvalue `QJsonValueRef`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray-iterator.html#operator-2a) and you are binding that to `v`. Also, this statement is completely wrong "Because the rvalue is a QJsonValue, the lvalue v is now a QJsonValueRef."...

Comment: @Mike Would you like to edit the answer as I think you'll be more accurate than me? Totally happy for you to do that rather than me correcting it badly.

Comment: @Mike I should have checked the `auto&& v` before changing the answer. I have now tried it and I get the warning "loop variable 'v' is always a copy because the range of type 'QJsonArray' does not return a reference". Can you help?

Comment: What compiler / version / compiler-flags  are you using to compile your program? I tried this code using various GCC, clang, MSVC versions and I couldn't reproduce the warning...

Comment: @Mike MacOS 10.13.3 (High Sierra), Qt Creator 4.6.0, Qt 5.10.1, Clang Code Model enabled

Comment: Well, to silence the warning you need to fall back to `for(auto v : oldArray)` or use `//NOLINT`. I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50066139/2666212) about this warning (the question is talking about `vector<bool>` since more people are familiar with it, but the same logic applies here).

Comment: It turned out that the warning is just about making sure the code reflects the fact that there is a temporary object being returned; both solutions (`for auto v` and `for auto &&v`) are identical in terms of the number of objects being constructed/destructed, see the question for details. Sorry for the noise. Feel free to edit the answer however you like :)

Comment: @Mike Thanks for following up on this. I read that other question. Let's leave the solution as it is, but I'll add a note about the warning in case others encounter it.

Comment: OK my turn to create lots of noise :-/ I've reread that other question and, if I've understood right, although the assignment to `auto&& v` doesn't involve a copy, a copy happens implicitly within the ranged-for operator. If that's the case, `auto v` is essentially equivalent to `auto&& v` but `auto v` explicitly expects to be receiving a copy. In which case `auto v` would be the better solution. You understand this better than me, so let me know if I'm wrong before I change the solution please.

Comment: :-| You already did! D'oh. I've just added a note about the clang warning. Job done I hope.