# What is clang's 'range-loop-analysis' diagnostic about?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings, clang++, copy-elision

### Background:

Consider the following [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FdnV8VnfU8v7ypCs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<bool> vectorBool{false, true};
    for(const auto &element : vectorBool) std::cout << std::boolalpha << element << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

It emits the warning:

```
test.cpp:6:21: warning: loop variable 'element' is always a copy because the range of type 'std::vector<bool>' does not return a reference [-Wrange-loop-analysis]
    for(const auto &element : vectorBool) std::cout << std::boolalpha << element << ' ';
                    ^
test.cpp:6:9: note: use non-reference type 'std::_Bit_reference'
    for(const auto &element : vectorBool) std::cout << std::boolalpha << element << ' ';
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

When compiled using clang with the `range-loop-analysis` diagnostic enabled:

```
$ clang++ -Wrange-loop-analysis -o test test.cpp
```

---

### Questions:

According to https://reviews.llvm.org/D4169, the warning emits when:

> for (const Foo &x : Foos), where the range Foos only return a copy. Suggest using the non-reference type so the copy is obvious

I completely understand that `std::vector<bool>`'s iterators return a copy of a proxy type (instead of a reference), but I disagree with the statement "so the copy is obvious":

1. **Where exactly is that "hidden" copy operation taking place?** As far as I can see, we are just binding a reference to a temporary object, and this should prolong the lifetime of the temporary to match that of the reference.
2. Even in case we have written `for(const auto element : vectorBool)` (so that the warning disappears), We should have no copy/move operations under [C++17's guaranteed copy elision rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/2666212) (and even in pre-C++17 when using any decent compiler), so **is this warning about making an *elided* copy operation obvious?!**

Comment: At first glance this warning looks silly/wrong to me for the code you posted.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's unfortunate that proxy types gets this warning, but I doubt analyzers can ever distinguish between proxies and some weird stuff. If all else fails, blame `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: @Passer By - `vector<bool>`, yeah, I wish it had never been created..

Comment: @PasserBy,  so, do you mean that there are cases where dereferencing iterators return a copy (without this copy being a proxy object)? I have never encountered such a case before, and I can't imagine why would something like this be done

Comment: @Mike I don't want to see that ever being done either. The analysis only looks at the type and deduce that the return value cannot possibly be the element in the container,  _something_ must have been copied. It then suggests writing `auto : Foos` to make obvious that fact. In this case, proxies conceptually didn't copy anything, but I doubt the analyzer can do anything about that. It's trying to warn people about the weird non-proxy case.

Comment: @Mike Consider some sort of range adapter like `uppercase(some_vector_of_strings)`.  It can't possibly return a reference to the object in the container since it has to modify each element before it returns it.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Actually, that worries me now that you mentioned it. That is exactly what ranges v3 is doing. Probably breaks the analysis extremely hard

Comment: Here is an interesting series of articles regarding this topic: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/15/autorefref-always-works/
Recommendation: always use `for ( auto&& element : container )`

Comment: @Ignitor Whenever you use a reference you are adding very subtle dependencies.  If I do `for (auto const element:container)`, I **know** that the `element` is not mutated by any mutation of the container in the body of the for loop.  While that is rare, when it happens it very often generates a bug.  If the cost of copying the element is low, using reference aliases on it is borrowing trouble...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++17 a range based for loop is defined as

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

And

```
range_declaration = *__begin;
```

Is the point where the range variable is initialized.  Typically `*__begin` returns a reference so in

```
for (const auto& e : range_that_returns_references)
```

`e` can be eliminated and we can just work with the element from the range.  In

```
for (const auto& e : range_that_returns_proxies_or_copies)
```

`e` can't be eleminated.  `*__begin` will create a proxy or copy and then we bind that temporary to `e`.  That means in every iteration you have an object that is being created and destroyed, which could be costly, and is not obvious as you are using a reference.  The warning wants you to use a non reference type to make it obvious that you are not actually working with the element from the range but instead a copy/proxy of it.

Comment: I see, so the warning is just about making sure the user understands that there is a temporary object being created (and not just references being passed around). However, in my opinion, the warning should not be emitted when the user is using `for(auto && e : vectorBool)` since using forwarding references is enough to indicate that the user is willing to accept any kind of return type...

Comment: @Mike I think that would be reasonable.  I'm not coming up with anything that where it would be non obvious.