# Range based for loop: difference between vector<bool> and vector<int>

Tags: c++

In the simple code below `for (auto& v : vb)` does not compile whereas `for (auto & v : vi)` compiles fine.

The only difference is that `vb` is a vector of `bool` and `vi` is a vector of `int`.

The error message:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Vb_referencestd::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Vbase>>' to 'std::_Vb_referencestd::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Vbase>> &'`

is not really helpful for me.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<bool> vb{ false, false };
  for (auto & v : vb)  //<<< error messages refers to this line
    v = true;   
  
  std::vector<int> vi{ 1, 2 };
  for (auto & v : vi)  //<<< compiles fine
    v = 2;
}
```

`bool` being a builtin C++ type (basically a special kind of `char`), both range based loops should compile.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` does some fancy stuff to pack bools into a bitfield. As a result, dereferencing iterators return some proxy object and not just a `bool&`. Many complain about the standard making so, but this cannot be changed due to backward compatibility. Consider using `std::vector<uint8_t>` or adjust your code to account for the existence of those proxy objects.

Comment: @JeJo I know, the question was specifically about bool vs int. And the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079390/range-for-loops-and-stdvectorbool) and the first comment perfectly address it.