# range based for loop with existing variable

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, gcc, visual-c++

Using a range based for loop in C++11 with an existing variable, I would expect that variable to be filled with the value of the last iteration after the loop. However, I've gotten different results when I tested it.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(43);
  v.push_back(99);

  int last = -50;
  for (last : v)
    std::cout << ":" << last << "\n";

  std::cout << last;
  return 0;
}
```

1. MSVC 2013 doesn't seem to support range based for loops without type declaration
2. GCC-5.1 either automatically introduces a new variable or sets it back to the initial value, giving

   > :2
   >   :43
   >   :99
   >   -50

I guess MSVC is just being MSVC again, but what about GCC here? Why is `last` not `99` in the last line?

---

Given the [definition by the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), I would expect the behaviour I described in the first sentence.

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression ; 
  for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
       __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    range_declaration = *__begin; 
    loop_statement 
  } 
}
```

`range_declaration` being `last` and not `int last`, this should modify the existing variable.

Comment: Does that even compile? I thought the `last` bit had to be a declaration.

Comment: Ah, this must be them pre-emptively implementing [n3994](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm) which didn't make it into C++17.

Comment: @TartanLlama Thanks, I see now that "`range_declaration"` was chosen for a good reason. I wasn't able to deduce that it actually **had** to be a declaration and thought it could be any assignable expression.

Comment: related answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32706051/86967

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GCC implemented standards proposal [n3994](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm), which suggests that `for (elem : range)` be syntactic sugar for `for (auto&& elem : range)`. This didn't make it into C++17, so the functionality has been removed from more recent versions of GCC.

The named variable used to iterate over the range must be a declaration according to `[stmt.ranged]`, so your code shouldn't compile.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it is the only one stating that the left side of the `:` actually has to be a declaration, not an arbitrary expression, and contains a reference to the standard. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 10):

Your code does not compile starting with gcc 6.1 (and for all clang versions):

```
main.cpp:12:8: error: range-based for loop requires type for loop variable
  for (last : v)
       ^
       auto &&
```

it looks like previous versions used auto implicitly here. The fact that you get -50 as last output is because `for` introduces local scope for last, so after `for` ends, last from outer scope was used.

---

I did a little digging and this was on purpose under gcc: [N3994, terse range-for](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm), which shortly is doing following:

```
A range-based for statement of the form
    for ( for-range-identifier : for-range-initializer ) statement
is equivalent to
    for ( auto&& for-range-identifier : for-range-initializer ) statement
```

then it didn`t make it to c++17 and was removed here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=229632

Comment: So MSVC wasn't being MSVC again!

Comment: newest VS (http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) also does not compile this.

Comment: gcc 5.1.0 compiles it in c++1z mode

Comment: 5.2.0 and 5.3.0 compiles it either

Comment: @Borgleader OP did not say that it requires c++1z

Answer (score 2):

Your program doesn't compile with my g++ 4.9.2.

Compile with clang++ 3.5 (with a warning: "range-based for loop with implicit deduced type is a C++1z extension [-Wc++1z-extensions]")

But clang++ use different `last` variables

With the following modified program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(43);
  v.push_back(99);

  int last = -50;

  std::cout << "extern last pointer: " << long(&last) << '\n';

  for ( last : v)
   {
     std::cout << ": " << last << " ; pointer: " << long(&last) << '\n';
   }

  std::cout << "extern last pointer again: " << long(&last) << '\n';
  std::cout << ": " << last << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following output

```
extern last pointer: 140721376927168
: 2 ; pointer: 38101008
: 43 ; pointer: 38101012
: 99 ; pointer: 38101016
extern last pointer again: 140721376927168
: -50
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the standard, a range based for loop is producing the same output as:

```
{
  auto&& __range = expression;
  for (auto __begin = begin-expression,
            __end = end-expression;
       __begin != __end;
       ++__begin)
  {
    declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

As you can see, the iteration variable `__begin` is being defined in its own scope.

> Why is last not 99 in the last line?

You have two variables called `last`. One is in the scope of your main function and holds the value `-50`. The second variable is defined in the scope of the range based for loop.

Inside the loop, printing the `last` variable prints the one from the same scope (ie. from the range based for loop). After the loop however, printing `last` will again print the variable from the same scope which is the one holding `-50`

Comment: `declaration` has to be an actual declaration. And `last` is not.

Comment: @Nicol, I'm answering Niklas' second question to why he's getting the values he's stating in GCC5.1. Changing `last` to an actual type declaration would not change that.