# How do I compare a char string with argv in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to compare a character string with the argv argument.

I have this in my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Now if I write

```
if (argv[2] == 'squared')
```

the IDE tells me that I have a multiple character constant or that the char* is too long for its type or something similiar.

Is there a way to compare argv to a character string? I've even used strcmp but that gives me a segmentation fault when the program runs.

I also tried a for loop and incremented argv[i] but that gave me an error too.

Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: `strcmp` is the way to do it, not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help comparing an argv string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803776/help-comparing-an-argv-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use strcmp and a real string, not a multi character constant.

```
strcmp(argv[2], "squared") == 0
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `strncmp`. The standard specifies that both `"squared"` and `argv[2]` are zero-terminated strings (assuming that `argc` is at least 3.)

Comment: If you want to match the whole string, `strncmp` is of no use when one of the strings is a string literal :)

Comment: I am sure I tried that but I still get a segmentation fault. It doesn't happen if I  remove the strcmp.  I'll give it another go and see what I'm doing wrong though. Thanks. I will get back to you guys in a while.

Comment: @watabou check if argc is greater than 2 otherwise you don't have argv[2]

Comment: __Do not__ write `if (strcmp(3))`, __do not__ write `if (strcmp(argv[2], "squared"))`.

__DO__ write `if ((argc > 3) && (strcmp(argv[2], "squared") == 0))`

Comment: @Eregrith PS: argc > 2 is enough…

Comment: Ow yeah, sorry, my bad. At work I have to deal with code from 1995 where some guy thought it would be great to re-implement operator[] and do index - 1 so when you use str[1] it gets the char at index 0 ... GREAT now i'm contaminated

Answer (score 3):

Try strcmp(3). 
In your case, you would have to use `strcmp(argv[2], "squared");`
Check out [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) manual page for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strcmp` for that:

```
if(strcmp(argv[2], "squared") == 0)  /* returns true if argv[2] is "squared" */
```

Answer (score 1):

*strcmp()*/*strncmp()* is the way to go. And make sure your strings are null-terminated ;)

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes in C are only used for single characters, not strings. So you'd write 'a' for the a character, but "hello world" for a string.

There is a difference between 'a' and "a" incidentally - "a" has a zero-terminator on the end, so it's actually a two-character string. That's important because you have to remember that char arrays need to be one character longer than the string you're storing in the them.

To compare strings, use strcmp, like this:

```
if (strcmp(argv[2], "squared") == 0)
{
    //they are equal
}
```